# Proving Linear Independence of Gaussian Functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Assume that I have a summation of $N$ Gaussian functions with different means $\mu_i$, $1 \leq i \leq N$ as in
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i e^{ - (x- \mu_i)^2 },
$$
where the $a_i$ are real numbers. Is it true that the only solution is given when all $a_i$ are zero, i.e., the Gaussians are linearly independent functions? If so, how does the proof look like? Thank you for your help.

Comment: multiply by $e^{x^2}$ and consider growth rate as $x \rightarrow \infty$. It will be determinined by largest $\mu_i$, whose coefficient must therefore be 0. Get rid of it & repeat.

Comment: Hi mike, thanks for your comment. However, I am not sure what you mean by "growth rate".

Comment: in case your still interested, suppose they are ordered by decreasing $\mu_i$.  It is east to show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{x^2}e^{-2 \mu_1 x} \times$ your function $ = a_1e^{\mu_1^2}$ which then has to be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose
$$
0=\sum_{i=1}^N a_ie^{-(x-\mu_i)^2}=
e^{-x^2}\sum_{i=1}^N a_ie^{-\mu_i^2}e^{-2\mu_ix}
$$
and set $b_i=a_ie^{-\mu_i^2}$, $c_i=-2\mu_i$. Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^Nb_ie^{c_ix}=0
$$
with $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_N$ pairwise distinct. Suppose the thesis holds for $N-1$ functions and

1. Multiply by $c_N$: $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^Nb_ic_Ne^{c_ix}=0$
2. Differentiate: $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^Nb_ic_ie^{c_ix}=0$

Subtracting the two relations, we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}b_i(c_i-c_N)e^{c_ix}=0
$$
and, by the induction hypothesis, $b_i(c_i-c_N)=0$, whence $b_i=0$ for $i=1,\dots,N-1$. Therefore also $b_N=0$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this proof. You say "whence $b_i=0$ for $i=1, ..., N-1$, but I thought this is your induction hypothesis, so why differentiate, multiply and subtract? Also from what exactly follows the last sentence ("Therefore ...")?

Comment: @Christian The induction hypothesis is that $N-1$ exponentials (with pairwise distinct factors in the exponent) are linearly independent. So we conclude that $b_i(c_i-c_N)=0$; but $c_i\ne c_N$, for $i=1,2,\dots,N-1$. Thus we know that $b_i=0$ for $i=1,\dots,N-1$ and, substituting in the original expression, we get $b_Ne^{c_Nx}=0$, so $b_N=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.